# Trig triangles angle

Tags: c#, trigonometry

i have a start point and a end point. I want to work out the angle i have this formula that seems to work

```
double dx = end.X - start.X;
double dy = end.Y - start.Y;

double degrees = Math.Acos((-Math.Pow(dy, 2) + Math.Pow(dx, 2) + Math.Pow(dx, 2)) / (2 * Math.Pow(dx, 2)));
degrees = degrees * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Then i want to take the angle and extend the line's length. i have this so far

```
end.Y = (start.Y + (len * Math.Sin(angle)));
end.X = (start.X + (len * Math.Cos(angle)));
```

now this does not give me the right value.

white is original line and red is the extending

[image: white is original line and red is the extending]

what am i doing wro

Comment: by extending the line length you mean making it longer?

Comment: Why do you need the angle? Can't you simply compute the new end points by using the dx and dy values and normalizing them, then multiplying by len?

Comment: that is the complete code... yes making it longer. mtjames explain what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand your calculation of `degrees` - `deg = acos((2dx^2 - dy^2)/(2dx^2))`? Where did you get this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant in code:

```
double dx = end.X - start.X;
double dy = end.Y - start.Y;

double dlen = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

dx = dx / dlen;
dy = dy / dlen;

end.X = start.X + (dx * len);
end.Y = start.Y + (dy * len);
```

Comment: one problem i am gettig -degrees.

Comment: @Pintac - you don't get to this problem with @mrjames' solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to continue your line, first you'll have to find the function which defines your line.

this is a "simple" line ... it's function is f(x)=ax+b. Find a and b.

To find a :

```
a = (start.y - end.y) / (start.x - end.x)
// easy, isn't it ?
```

To find b :

```
b = (start.y) - (a * start.x)
// you can check switching "start" by "end"
```

No deal with angles, cosinus or sinus ...

Bye

Comment: I realize that this is a somewhat old thread, but this answer is wrong b/c in case your line segment is vertical, you end up having a div by 0! The OP's approach, using trig functions is actually bettter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the hypotenuse (which you don't need) you should use a tangent trig function
Like

```
  double rads = Math.Atan(dy/dx);
```

Your degree calc is quite convoluted although my way involves keeping track of quadrants. See:  http://www.mathwizz.com/algebra/help/help29.htm

Comment: one problem i am gettig - degrees

Comment: you say degrees, but what units is "angle" in your sample? it should be in radians. is that maybe all that is wrong. personally Guillaume's answer is the best way to solve your issue

Comment: You should actually use the ATAN2() function instead, to avoid the div by 0 problem.

Comment: Guillaume's answer is actually not the best way as it is possibly wrong. @mrjames answer is actually the correct way to do it.